# javaScript, react-native, super.method is undefined

Tags: javascript, class, extends

React-native. In child class, super.method is undefined. Why is the parent class method not visible in the super?

```
export class ParentClass {
    constructor(field) {
        this.field = field;
    }

    protected ruleMatch = (type: string): string => {
        return type;
    }

    onGetRule = (type: string) => {
        return this.ruleMatch(type);
    }
}

export class ChildrenClass extends ParentClass {
    // extends method of parent Class
    onGetRule = (type: string) => {
        if(type === 'typeA') {
            return 'anything';
        }
        return super.onGetRule(type); // TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I override inherited methods when using JavaScript ES6/ES2015 subclassing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39886830/how-do-i-override-inherited-methods-when-using-javascript-es6-es2015-subclassing)

Answer (score 0):

You defined your method `onGetRule` as field declaration. Change the syntax of `onGetRule`-method to

```js
export class ParentClass {
    constructor(field) {
        this.field = field;
    }

    protected ruleMatch = (type: string): string => {
        return type;
    }

    onGetRule(type: string) {
        return this.ruleMatch(type);
    }
}

export class ChildrenClass extends ParentClass {
    // extends method of parent Class
    onGetRule(type: string) {
        if(type === 'typeA') {
            return 'anything';
        }
        return super.onGetRule(type); // TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
    }
}
```

A field declarations create the prop on **each** class instance, rather than using the prototype-chain like class-methods.

It's like this:

```js
class ParentClass {
  constructor(field) {
    this.field = field;
    this.onGetRule = (type) => {
        return type;
    }
  }
}
```

and so `super.onGetRule` will be undefined, because it's missing in the prototype-chain.